# Update field without rest API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a **model.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformation(models.Model):
    ...
    awaiting_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to make `awaiting_confirmation = True`  in code. But forbid `awaiting_confirmation` update via RestAPI call.

**views.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformationUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedDriver,)
    serializer_class = UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer
    queryset = serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()


        def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            partial = kwargs.pop("partial", False)
            instance = self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.get(
                user=self.request.user
            )
    
            self.mark_user_as_new()
            # awaiting_confirmation = True # I WANT SOMETHING LIKE THIS
            serializer = self.get_serializer(
                instance, data=request.data, partial=partial
            )
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_update(serializer)
            return Response({"result": serializer.data})
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPaymentInformation
        fields = ("id", "full_name", "card_number", "account_number", "bik", "awaiting_confirmation")
```

How can I fix update method?

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer` you could set the `read_only_fields = ('awaiting_confirmation',)`, so your serializer would become:

```
class UserPaymentInformationUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPaymentInformation
        fields = ("id", "full_name", "card_number", "account_number", "bik", "awaiting_confirmation")
        read_only_fields = ("awaiting_confirmation",)
```

This would mean it'd still be returned in the serializer data but it would not be possible to update it through an API request.

Comment: THank you, but how can I made  awaiting_confirmation = True in update method?

Comment: can you just put `instance. awaiting_confirmation = True` before you call `self.perform_update(serializer)`?